Curing the petrified condition, using Remastered rules
In the Pathfinder 2nd Edition Legacy ruleset, the spell Stone to Flesh is available for curing petrification. However, this spell hasn't been updated to the Remastered release. What methods are available, in Remastered books, for curing a character who has been petrified?

Spells

Sure Footing 6th rank. This is the Remaster replacement for Stone to Flesh.

Alchemy

Greater Salve of Antiparalysis.

Spells that might work in a specific situation

Cleanse Affliction 3rd/4th rank. This only works if its caused by a Curse/Disease/Poison and ending that would remove the Petrify as well.
Dispel Magic. This only works if it's caused by an ongoing magical effect. Note that if they were Petrified by the Petrify spell, Dispel Magic will not work. Petrify's duration ends when they become Petrified so there is no ongoing spell to Dispel.

